# Data corrupted when sending from template to component lifecycle method?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**EMBER VERSION 3.10**

**DESCRIPTION**

If I pass an array of objects from a template(after iterating the array in the template view) to a component and try to access the data in one of the lifecycle methods of the component. The data is corrupted.

**CODE**

> controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  users: [{name:1},{name:2},{name:3}]
});
```

> templates/application.hbs

```
{{#each users as |user|}}
  <p>{{user.name}}</p>
{{/each}}

<FilterUsers @users={{users}} />
{{outlet}}
```

> templates/components/filter-users.hbs

```
empty file
```

> components/filter-users.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    console.log(this.get('users'));
  }
});
```

**OUTPUT**

**with bug**

[image]

**without bug**

If i removed each block from `application.hbs` which iterates the array. I get proper results.

> templates/application.hbs

```
<FilterUsers @users={{this.users}} />
{{outlet}}
```

[image]

**I'm new to ember, so is it a bug or am i not doing the ember way ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is a debug feature!

Your objects are wrapped in proxy objects. because after you've used `{{user.name}}` in the template you may not do `this.get('users')[0].name = "bla"` but must do `this.get('users')[0].set('name', 'bla')` for ember to update the template. The proxy object will throw an error if you try this.
Because proxies are not available in all browsers and may have performance impacts this is not done in a production build. So in production builds there are no proixies.

(sidenote: if proxies were avaliable under all circumstances you would not need to do `this.get('users')[0].set('name', 'bla')` at all. Without proxies tho its impossible to detect `this.get('users')[0].name = "bla"` and this would break. So the proxie in development should help you to avoid this by throwing the errors)

The important part is: The proxy should have *no effect*! The only thing that looks different is the debug log, because proxy information are shown. So you have to open up the objects to see the `name` and then click on it to execute the getter:

[image: screenshot]

However code like this will still work:

```
console.log(this.get("users")[0].name);
```

Comment: But why does it give proper results if each block is removed. Check the without bug section i have mentioned. The result must be consistent irrespective of the each block is present or not. Can you elaborate on that ?

Comment: Without the each block you don't use the objects in the template. So it's not dangerous to use a native setter. So it's not wrapped in a warning proxy. Also the behavior is not changed by adding the proxy. So it is consistent.

Comment: To be clear: it's a proper result in each case! Just in the debug console you see the debug error.